# Batch Class execute using Cron job Schedulable

Tags: apex, batch, schedule

I am trying to run my Batch Class called UltimateParentAccount for every 6am and 12pm using a Cron Job Schedulable name ScheduleUltimeParentAccountBatch.

I tested my batch class and it works well, and then I create a schedulable class which is ScheduleUltimeParentAccountBatch and called the batch class to set a Cron Job.

But I encoutered an Error:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String, String, UltimateParentAccount) from the type System
```

Here is my code for my schedulable class:

```
global class ScheduleUltimeParentAccountBatch implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        UltimateParentAccount upc = new UltimateParentAccount();
        String sch = '0 0 6,12 ? * *';
        System.schedule('My Job', sch, upc);
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong? And I checked the some docx about the syntax of schedule method and it seems fine to me but then still I encoutered an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduler is a class that executes on your specified time. What you are trying to do is Schedule a Batch, Which is not possible directly,

UltimateParentAccount is a batch.

The way we execute batch is

```
Database.executeBatch(batchable Object)
```

So your Scheduler code will be:

```
global class ScheduleUltimeParentAccountBatch implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        UltimateParentAccount upc = new UltimateParentAccount();
        Database.exceuteBatch(upc );

    }
}
```

Now, to schedule the scheduler at a given time, in execute anon you will use.

```
String sch = '0 0 6,12 ? * *';
System.schedule('My Job', sch, new ScheduleUltimeParentAccountBatch());
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_async_overview.htm

Comment: I see,I guess there is no way to set a schedule to run a batch class, maybe I should set the cron job in the UI to make it run every day without using the execute anon.

Comment: You can make a single class implement Database.batchable and Schedulable, to make a schedulable batch

Comment: Do you have any sample or how to set a schedule in batch class?

Comment: You can refer this.  https://sfdc.guide/posts/writing-batchable-schedulable-apex-code/

Comment: I have run the batch class using your code stated above, how to abort this from execute anon?

Comment: Go to system.abortJob(jobId)